# An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

Tags: c#, .net, exception, signalr

I'm Trying to work with signalR for a recent project. I tried using some examples I found to make a .net server and client.

the examples can be found here :

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/SignalR.Client

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/SignalR.Hosting.Self.Samples

Ive tried running them both just on my local machine and the client connects to the server fine. When running a few tests Ive found that when debugging in visual studio if I just close the client the server waits a while and the gets the following exception.

**"An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection"**

Ive tried to catch the exception but visual studio refuses to catch it.

which appears to be a problem with the httplistener class.

I'm running both the sever and the client on my local machine as console applications using visual studio 2010 for debugging.

Ive tried searching for the problem everywhere and found nothing useful.

Has anyone else ran into this problem and does anybody know how to fix it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How you close your client? Do you properly close connection with server?

Comment: No I'm just shutting it down instantly, I wanted to see how the server reacts when I client disconnects suddenly. This of course is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using port 8080? Is this port being used by something else? It was for me when I got this exception.

Try changing the port you are using to something unlikely to be in use in both the host and the client.